# Ess sup non-measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes

Welcome, could You give an example that `ess sup` is non-measurable? I know example that`sup`is non-measurable and in that case `ess sup` is "better", but I need it more general.

Comment: From my understanding of the definition, $\text{ess sup}$ must be measurable.  I suppose if your measure space is not compete, you could change it on a null set to make it non-measurable...is that what you mean?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Are you talking about $\operatorname{esssup}_{x \in X} f(x,y)$, where $f : X\times Y \to \Bbb{R}$ is measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra? If you take the counting measure on $X$, you the supremum will coincide with the essential supremum, so maybe you should impose some additional assumption, like $X$ being $\sigma$-finite.